# Frequency distribution of values in tuples meeting a condition inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of list of tuples:

```
[[("AA","AA"),("QQ","")],[("CC",""),("QQ","")],...]
```

I would like to get the frequency each value appears as the first item of the tuple when the second item of the tuple is `""`.

Something like this for the above example:

```
{"QQ":2, "CC":1}
```

Comment: I would look at the [`collections`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module.

Comment: I was trying by creating a list with all occurrences and do collerctions.most_commons... but as my lists are quite big I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way...

Answer (score 7):

I'd do it using `collections.Counter` + `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> data = [[("AA","AA"),("QQ","")],[("CC",""),("QQ","")]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(left for left, right in chain.from_iterable(data) if not right)
Counter({'QQ': 2, 'CC': 1})
```

---

This works because `Counter` counts things that it's fed:

```
>>> Counter(["QQ", "QQ", "AA", "CC"])
Counter({'QQ': 2, 'AA': 1, 'CC': 1})
```

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` can be used to flatten `data`:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(data))
[('AA', 'AA'), ('QQ', ''), ('CC', ''), ('QQ', '')]
```

And we use the genexp to select only the terms where the second is empty (which for strings can be written simply `if not somestring`):

```
>>> list(left for left, right in chain.from_iterable(data) if not right)
['QQ', 'CC', 'QQ']
```

Comment: A guide to list comprehensions/generator expressions - http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk.

Comment: @dsm 1.000 thanks! is it possible to reference the tupple[0] as left? or I am missing something?

Comment: @user2950162: I *gave* the 0th item the name `left` in `for left, right in ..`.  I could have written `(tup[0] for tup in chain.from_iterable(data) if not tup[1])` instead.